# OAuth authentication client side security issues

Tags: security, authentication, oauth

I understand the security issues around attempting to use OAuth for authentication from a provider's point of view.  However I've been asked to provide users the facility to log on to a new web application using OAuth and obtain their basic identity info from the likes of Google and Twitter, from which a new user account within the client application will be created.  Additionally users will be able to regster/login directly via user/passwords for anyone not wishing to use third party accounts.

We do not require any access to the user's details/info or providers APIs, just their basic identity when they first logon, and of course allow them to login via the provider in the future.  Not exactly the use case OAuth is intended for, OpenId would have been preferred, but OAuth has been specified and without valid concerns would need to be adhered to.

My question is how safe is it to assume that the user has correctly authenticated themselves with the relevant provider.  If I trust say Google to perform adequate authentication and I obtain an access token and their identity, presumably I can consider that a legitimate user?  There are obviously issues if some one has access to the resource owners machine and saved passwords in the browser but that issue is present for those users who elect to register directly.

Presumably it possible to fake an access token, e.g. man in the middle pretending to be google?  A MITM could fake an access token and supply identity details that matched a registered user's google id?  I don't see anything for a client to know that the information definitely came from the provider.  Obviously this problem is not unique to OAuth.

Are there another ways someone could illegitimately access an account that used OAuth to *authenticate* themselves.

Comment: First of all, an access token is specific to the application and **not** the end user. To obtain an access token, the application must be registered to the service provider. Secondly, OAuth has **no reference** to the user authentication process whatsoever and the user authentication only provided to allow the user to accept whether the application can access its protected resource. So, how will faking the access token really be suitable if there application itself has never been registered by the service provider?

Comment: Obviously the applciation would be registered.  I had thought that if something could intercept comms to the OAuth provider they could pretend to be them, return a random token and then provide a captured google id when requested.  Google is never contacted and the application 'assumes' a user has gone to google and authenticated themselves.  From what I can see a client has no way of validating the token comes from Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OAuth allows that an **application** to **access** a *specific* user resource (that has been provided permission by the user) and it cannot go outside that scope. I have not seen the documentation that refers to creating a new user using OAuth based application.

That being said:

> We do not require any access to the user's details/info or providers
>   APIs, just their basic identity when they first logon

This violates OAuth authorization process. The Service Provider does the authentication and provides the relevant tokens (based on the success of the authentication). This is to ensure that there are no 3rd party authentication done during the OAuth authentication process.

> My question is how safe is it to assume that the user has correctly
>   authenticated themselves with the relevant provider.

This all depends on the service provider itself. To conform to OAuth protocol, one of the requirement is that user authentication **must be done** in a secured transport layer with a digital certificate (for HTTP, it must be done in HTTPS). OAuth consumer don't have any reference to the authentication process. Also the authentication process basically asks the user if the consumer can access the resource of the specific user (and not anyone else, since he doesn't have authorization to it).

> Is it possible to fake an access token, e.g. man in the middle
>   pretending to be google?

Spoofing a Service Provider *IS* possible but it'll be tedious. For one, you will have to create a whole OAuth handshake process, create the *exact* API as the service provider, also setup an environment that is secured (as OAuth recommends). The only thing the spoofing service provider can obtain is the client credentials. If it has its user credentials, there is no need to use the application as there is no way of providing a user credentials using an application to do malicious damage.

Secondly, access tokens do expire so even if you spoof and retrieve an access token, the original application owner can ask for the service provider to block the application and the access token can be useless.

A man in the middle attack won't be possible. You will have to replicate the service provider in a sense that the end user won't be able to distinguish between the original and the spoofing service provider in order to capture all relevant credentials (from both the application and end user).

Comment: "I have not seen the documentation that refers to creating a new user using OAuth based application."  - Sorry I wasn't clear.  First time a user logs on via provider a new account will be prompted to be created within the client application, the client will request the identity of the resource owner from the provider for this purpose.

Comment: "This violates OAuth authorization process", again not clear, sorry.  I appreciate that the client provides no part in authorisation, actually one of the reasons OAuth was specified for this project was so we hold less information.

Comment: Thanks.  Am I right in thinking that you are implying that it is fairly safe to assume that a successful response from a provider means that the user as validly authenticated themselves?  I'm not worried about anyone trying to access resources in the provider, just spoofing our application.

Comment: There is no account created. The service provider will have a "token" knowing that the user authorized the OAuth consumer. The OAuth consumer has no knowledge of which user authenticated and can't link it to any of the tokens provided by the service provider.

Comment: `Am I right in thinking that you are implying that it is fairly safe to assume that a successful response from a provider means that the user as validly authenticated themselves?` Yes. If an invalid authentication was done, the service provider will provide you with an error denying access. To spoof your application, they will need to read your application ID and credential, which means they must be able to decrypt the message from the secured transport layer or spoof the entire service provider.

Comment: Excellent, thanks very much for that.  Your comments and a bit more reading have put my concerns at rest.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly saying, the scenario from your last sentence is the truth.

But you should realise that the security is a huge and complex issue, especially in client side. It's not happen just in a single point but many points through the whole internet access life cycle. The scenario you given is not what OAuth try to solve.

Comment: Yeah I appreciate security is a huge issue.  Once logged in best practices are always used and the application subjected to various security tests.  For OAuth I'm *only* really concerned in someone pretending to be them and accessing that user's information, which is it's self important, but they won't have access to any high value resources, those are protected via AD.